Implementing a TM with FIFO Machine
I am attempting to simulate a TM on a FIFO machine. My initial approach is the following:
\begin{align*}
\text{Starting string:} & \quad \text{uabv}\rightarrow bv\#ua \\
\text{Step 1:} & \quad \text{v#uac} \quad \text{(Pop b, Push c)} \\
\text{Step 2:} & \quad \text{#uacv} \quad \text{(Pop v, Push v)} \\
\text{Step 3:} & \quad \text{uacv#} \quad \text{(Pop #, Push #)} \\
\text{Step 4:} & \quad \text{acv#u} \quad \text{(Pop u, Push u)} \\
\text{Result:} & \quad \text{a is at the front === one step left}
\end{align*}
What I am attempting to do is simulate the standard configuration of a TM such that the leftward movement may be described as: $$uaq_ibv \quad\text{yields}\quad uq_jacv$$
While I have in away simulated a step to the left, I run into the following issue: How is one to know how many pops to make? The answer is clearly the number of symbols on the left side plus the number of symbols on the right side. But I was wondering is it possible to make a FIFO machine (a PDA with a queue instead of stack) do something like that? Pop (m+n) times?
My gut feeling is that such a question cannot be answered, and I am wondering if anyone can offer any insight to that, or as well as maybe a different thought approach to the problem.

Yes we can simulate a TM tape by a FIFO queue. As you suggest we keep the tape on the queue with a marker $\#$ to separate the left and right parts of the tape as determined by the position of the reading head.
A move to the left can be simulated by fully "rotating" contents of the FIFO. There might be more clever tricks, but I can only do one step to the left by rotating twice. The first rotation discovers the last symbol of the FIFO.
To avoid misunderstanding, my FIFO is denoted (top) abcdefg (bot) and I can dequeue/pop from top, and enqueue/push at bottom.
Here is my naive solution. (To notation is also by example, to avoid indexed symbols: so I write abcdefg rather than $a_1a_2\dots a_n$)

start with abcdefg
mark the current position at the queue abcdefg$
rotate (pop and push) until marker is found, but delay pushing a little. We get to $abcdef with stored g
now push marker $ and g, effectively swapping them abcdef$g
continue rotation until marker is at top again $gabcdef and pop marker to obtain gabcdef as required


Ahhhh.... This makes much more sense. I did more brainstorming today and knew that the marker had to be dynamically updated somehow, but I could not really figure out exactly how. This makes much more sense. I came up with an even naiver today where I simply just mark the starting string, but it seems that that method only allows left movements. This seems like I could construct right movements from this as well... Thank you!
